# Replacing \emptyset symbol with one from a different font family in LaTeX

Tags: latex, fonts

So I quite like the Anttor fonts and I'd like to use them in LaTeX. Everything is nice, except the `\emptyset` symbol is ugly. I'd like to just `\renewcommand` the null set command, but I can't work out how to call, say, the computer modern `\emptyset` when using a different font family everywhere else.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\font\cmsy = cmsy10 at 12pt
\hbox{\cmsy \char 59}
\font\msbm = msbm10 at 12pt
\hbox{\msbm \char 63}
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [imageban.ru](http://i2.imageban.ru/out/2010/07/01/f833a099025778a2fa26361f7cd0a0ef.png))</sub>

Comment: would you mind commenting to explain what this code is doing? what does `\cmsy` mean?

Comment: Ok. `\cmsy` is my macro. It is defined by `\font` command. `\cmsy` is set to font `cmsy10` at 12 pt height. `cmsy10` has `emptyset` character (59th).